# NOT Every permutation can be expressed as the product transpositions

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

I read the following claim:

> Every permutation can be expressed as the product of one and only one
> of the following:
>
> an odd number of transpositions ⟺ odd permutation an even number of
> transpositions ⟺ even permutation

But I don't think this is correct at all, a transposition contains exactly 2 numbers so what about the following  permutation: (1)(2), how can you write in the the mentioned way?

Comment: In this context, the identity permutation can be considered an even permutation, as it can be expressed as the product of zero transpositions, which is an even number. In general, the identity permutation is considered even, and it belongs to the alternating group as well.

Comment: In addition to being the product of zero transpositions, the identity can also be written as $(1)(2) = (12)(12)$, which is the product of two transpositions. This is of course still even.

Comment: @rumathe do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ronno, no you can do it if you want

Comment: @JaapScherphuis do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ronno No, but feel free to incorporate it if you write one.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can write the trivial permutation as either the *empty product* of transpositions, or as a product where all the terms cancel each other, for example $(12)(12)$. In any case, the length of such a product of transpositions will be even.